# How to configure QA stage to run smoke tests?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline that currently deploys to Azure App Service whatever artifact was generated by the CI build pipeline.

[image: release]

As you can see, I added a QA stage, and I would like to run some smoke tests through batch command `testrunner.bat --cat "EEDSmoke" --env test`. These smoke tests and batch file are hosted on bitbucket repo.

[image: EEDSmoke]

I looked for a task to checkout the bitbucket repo in the QA stage, however, im not finding any task like that!

[image: tasks]

What exactly do i need to do to make this QA staging process work?
Do i need to link the bitbucket repo to Azure repos?
If i search for checkout task, i get a marketplace extension called "Git Repository CLone" to which I think I would simply clone the repo onto the pipeline agent of which then i simply can run the batch command above...but idk if thats the right track

It is noteworthy to mention, that the QA stage has this default artifact linked to it:
[image: arti]

but technically, this isnt whats needed in the QA stage right...? Instead it has to be the smoke tests i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [Bitbucket Cloud service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-bbucket), and then create a separate build pipeline to checkout this bitbucket repo and then publish it as smoke artifacts, as below.
[image]

Thus you could add this smoke artifact as [artifact source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources) in release pipeline.
[image]

So now you can [select which artifacts you want to download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-download) for your stage.

The other way is using the [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run below command to clone the smoke test repository in the release QA stage.
`git clone https://username:password@bitbucket.org/workspace/repository.git -b branch name`, see: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/how-to-clone-a-repository-using-username-and-password/qaq-p/720507 for details.

Comment: I see! I think the part I was stuck on was the bitbucket connection. I didnt find an option to ”Get Sources” in the release pipeline stage, but I suppose that's what differentiates a build from release. So dont you think an easier way would be to just clone the smoke test repository in the release QA stage instead of retrieving it as an artifact? Or would that not really work?

Comment: I update my answer for your reference to clone the bitbucket repository directly.

Comment: But then if I Clone it, what would be the path of the directory where I have to then run the batch file in it? Is it `$(system.workingdirectory)`?

Comment: The path of the cloned repository directory is $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\repository name, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services for details.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Of course I'll accept and I also upvoted :)